# Get highlighted text

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm developing an application in which I need to get the current highlighted text of the user outside my application, is there any way to do this?

I've read that I can register as a service but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Isn't that what the clipboard is for? (I guess what you could do is make that application copy the text and then read it out.)

Comment: I don't want to force the user to do a copy, I only want him to highlight the text.

Comment: I meant programmatically making the application copy the text. This is reasonably easy using AppleScript, so it should be possible to replicate in ObjC somehow but I can't find where the docs for `AESendEvent()` is. (The function I've seen mentioned does this.)

Comment: @millimoose, that will replace the contents of the clipboard, which is the user's to control. You might cause permanent loss of important data. A service is the way to go, but OP doesn't want to use it for unexplained reasons.

Comment: Why don't you want to make a service?

Comment: Simply because of usability, I wan't to be able to get the highlighted text with the press of a shortcut.

Comment: @pirezas The user can assign a shortcut to your service. Honestly the one other thing comes to mind now is "use Accessibility APIs" but that's because they make everything possible but nothing easy.

Comment: As millimoose said, the user can assign a shortcut to any service. If you want your service to have a shortcut by default, you can do that, too. “get the highlighted text with the press of a shortcut” = make a service and define a keyboard shortcut in its service dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm developing an application in which I need to get the current highlighted text of the user outside my application, is there any way to do this?
>
> I've read that I can register as a service but I don't want to do that.

You really should. It's the right way.

> I don't want to force the user to do a copy, I only want him to highlight the text.

(Or her.)

That's how a service works: select something (usually text), then invoke a service.

> … I wan't to be able to get the highlighted text with the press of a shortcut.

You can do that, too.

Your service dictionary should look something like this:

```
<!--in Info.plist-->
<key>NSServices</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSMenuItem</key>
    <dict>
        <key>default</key>
        <string>ROT-13</string>
    </dict>

    <key>NSKeyEquivalent</key>
    <dict>
        <key>default</key>
        <!-- ⌘ is implicit, and an uppercase letter likewise implies shift -->
        <!-- Thus, this is ⌘-shift-e -->
        <string>E</string>
    </dict>

    <key>NSRequiredContext</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSServiceCategory</key>
        <string>public.text</string>
    </dict>

    <key>NSSendTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>NSStringPboardType</string>
    </array>

    ⋮
</dict>
```